# Skin for WindowedApplication drawing over components

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

In order to set a background image for my Desktop Flex application, I created a custom skin class, setting the `skinClass` property to my custom MXML skin. The host component is `SkinnableContainer`. I use a bitmap image for the custom MXML skin. Everything works fine, except that it's drawing over all my components. How do I get the skin to draw in the background? Should I move the Bitmap markup to somewhere else in my skin file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Flash Builder template for a SkinnableContainer Skin just make sure you insert the image object (eg, `BitmapImage`) in front of the `background:Rect` but behind the `contentGroup:Group`.  The `contentGroup` is where all visible display elements from the Application are displayed.

**Example**

```
<s:Rect id="background" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    ...
</s:Rect>

<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('assets/images/background.png')"/>

<s:Group id="contentGroup" ...>
   ...
</s:Group>
```

Comment: That's strange. I inserted it there, but it doesn't appear to have any effect. There's layout information in the contentGroup tag as well. Could that be interfering?

Comment: The layout settings in the contentGroup shouldn't be the problem.  However, do you have layout settings in the Skin itself? It should just be BasicLayout (or blank) if you do.  Also, are you using a s:BitmapImage, or something else? Are you embedding or loading at runtime?

Comment: I'm using the s:BitmapImage tag for my image. The s:BasicLayout tag is contained within the contentGroup.

Comment: I updated my answer to include some example code of how I implemented it.

Comment: Your example worked! Thanks! I had the markup in the wrong place.